# Unit Testing Json Serializer Configuration

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core

Is there any easy way to test the serializer middleware inside a .NET Core ASP.NET webpage.

E.g. I wanna confirm that given x JSON, it will get y Model object, using the currently configured app middleware.

I know under the hood it uses JSON.Net, but I want to confirm the specific configuration of my App (ideally without duplicating the configuration).

Comment: Please use [tag:asp.net-core-mvc] tag next time

Comment: As for your problem, have a look at Integration Testing section of the documentations http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/testing/integration-testing.html#the-test-host and the `TestServer` class as a rough bump into the right direction. One you start the client within the unit test you can either resolve the `MvcOptions` or `MvcJsonOptions` or just fire up a request and inspect the response

Comment: I am currently trying to figure out how I can set it to use User-Secrets? I have added exact same secrets to both projects, same userSecretsId to both projects.json, but still not picking up

Comment: Ok got it to work by doing `new WebHostBuilder()
                    .UseEnvironment(EnvironmentName.Development)
                    .UseStartup<Startup>()` which sets the environment to Development and tells WebHost to use UserSecrets, but now it UserSecrets complains that the project.json isn't copied over to the lcoation xunit runs its tests from

Comment: Had to add: `"buildOptions": {
    "copyToOutput": { "includeFiles": [ "project.json" ] }
  },`